# Changing Telegram Bot About Description

Tags: python, telegram, python-telegram-bot

I was building a telegram bot using python. and I was trying to find a method to change the bot about description of the bot from my code!

can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

No, you can do this only using @BotFather.

But you can try to use `telethon` library to programmatically access to it from your personal account.

Comment: yeah i was looking for a library like telethon, thanks